# Angular 6: Invalid time value

Tags: javascript, angular, datetime, epoch

I am trying to get two date and times as a string of numbers (epoch) so I can compare them. One is a new `Date()`:

```
today = new Date().valueOf();
```

And one is from an api response in the format:

```
scheduleDate: "2019-07-22T00:00+01:00"
```

The issue is I am trying to get the returned date in the correct format. When I try

```
var scheduleDate = new Date(scheduleDate).toISOString()
console.log("converted date:" + scheduleDate);
```

I get the error:

> Invalid time value

How do I get the returned date into epoch format?

Thanks

Comment: `new Date('2019-07-22T00:00+01:00').toISOString()` works fine, maybe one of the scheduleDate in the API answer is misformed

Comment: nothing here is specific to angular

Answer (score 1):

Your `scheduleDate` variable must be `undefined`. Are you sure it's being assigned properly?

[image]

```
(function() {

    //number (milleseconds)
    const today = new Date().valueOf();

    //string
    const scheduleDate = undefined; //"2019-07-22T00:00+01:00";

    const scheduleDate2 = new Date(scheduleDate).toISOString()

    console.log(typeof today);
    console.log(typeof scheduleDate);

    console.log("converted date: " + scheduleDate);
}
)();
```

More worryingly, why are you converting a date string to a date and then back to a string (same value).

Answer (score 0):

You are missed to assign the value

`scheduleDate= "2019-07-22T00:00+01:00"`

Then try its working

```
> scheduleDate= "2019-07-22T00:00+01:00"
'2019-07-22T00:00+01:00'
> new Date(scheduleDate)
2019-07-21T23:00:00.000Z
> var scheduleDate = new Date(scheduleDate).toISOString()
undefined
> scheduleDate
'2019-07-21T23:00:00.000Z'
> console.log("converted date:" + scheduleDate);
converted date:2019-07-21T23:00:00.000Z
```

Comment: I am confused? The value is assigned in the response. scheduleDate is already assigned.

Comment: in above you are posting like hash `scheduleDate: "2019-07-22T00:00+01:00"
`